# Javascript Invalid or Unexpected token (\u0)

Tags: javascript, apache, virtualbox, centos7

[image: Javascript Error]

As you will see in the image there is a number of red dots that are apparently each identify as **\u0**

**File Content or Editor Make no difference.**

The JS file being compiled or not compiled makes no difference, in fact more red dots appear in a non minified version because of spaces and new lines, even a blank file loaded and then adding something simple like console.log('abc') will result in all red dots only;

**Adding Content**

These invisible and unselectable characters appear the same number of times on the end of the file as the number of any other characters that I have typed out in any other part of the script.

> The invisible characters are not in the actual file itself on disk only in the one served by the web server.

**Deleting Content**

If i boot the VM and then delete characters out from anywhere in the JS script then the same number of chars will vanish from the END of the content in a webresponse request for the file.

**Unmodified use**

When I first boot up the VM and visit the website in a browser there is no error ever on multiple requests as long as the file is never modified in any way.

**Conclusion**

If I modify the file in any way while the VM is running the result is as if the server has somehow kept a snapshot of what the byte size of the file was when the server either first booted or the content was first served. Then upon making alterations to the content of the file while the server is running it either chops off content if made smaller or pads out with \u0 if made bigger as if it is padding the file.

**Can clear the fault its not permenant**

If I reboot the VM after making the file corrupt and refresh the request for the js file with the modifications that previously cause the error, the error is gone and my new changes are fine.

I can also undo the last changes that corrupted the response and normal operation will continue.

> This issue only just started happening since the 18th November give or take a couple of days and I had been running the setup for over a month prior without issue, the only thing I remember changing recently is a **couple of windows updates last week**?

I am running Virtualbox VM Centos 7, Apache 2.4.6 + PHP 7.1.12 on Windows 10 with the source code directory mounted to the VM using VBox Guest Additions shared folder configuration.

> It seems this issue is related to the VM and it's serving of the
>   assets, some form of padding and culling if the file changed after being loaded.

Restarting the httpd service has no affect, only rebooting the VM after every file modification clears the issue.

Has anyone else run into this problem or able to reproduce it?

**VM Setup (Reproduction)**

Here are the instructions I have been building up as I learn how to create and run a local development environment if you want to try and reproduce the issue:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11cBF75hfcehB3np4nlLhc1EqIOKVchKIuQJyrvn8ztk

**UPDATE 1 - 26/11/17**

I have tried rebuilding a new VM from scratch, still same problem.

I have noticed it is also happening to CSS files, as a test I changed the following code:

```
.flexData.tools .settings:hover {
    color: #0a0a0a;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=flexData.css.map */
```

to add a class called test:

```
.flexData.tools .settings:hover {
    color: #0a0a0a;
}
.test {
    color:blue;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=flexData.css.map */
```

Results in this at the end of the file served by the server looking like this:

```
.flexData.tools .settings:hover {
    color: #0a0a0a; 
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=flexData.css.map */
�������������������������
```

Notice how the test class is missing before the comment and the strange chars have appeared after the comment.

Then I rebooted the VM then pressed F5 (refresh) in my browser, the chars vanish and my test class appears:

```
.flexData.tools .settings:hover {
    color: #0a0a0a; }
.test {
    color:blue;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=flexData.css.map */
```

I checked the HTML source code response, it is **not** doing this to the HTML output from PHP.

**UPDATE 2 - 26/11/17**

> I installed XAMP and tested all the issues above... None of the file
>   modifications caused the error so this confirms there is some sort of
>   file cache issue going here with the VM or the httpd service in the
>   VM.

Comment: Try making a clean file in another editor and upload it again

Comment: Has nothing to do with what editor is used or what content is actually in the file. The server/VM somehow is caching the byte size of the file.
Tried notepad, notepadd++ just in case.

Comment: Any time I've seen those characters they were always in the file itself and cleaning the file resolved it

Comment: This occasion definitely not, the file served is not the same as the file on the disk if you open it your self.

Comment: Is it being cached? Is it saved as utf-8 or getting served with some other charset in headers?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You are joking... right how can i show people invisible characters without a screenshot...

Comment: @charlietfl this issue will be something to do with a form of caching somewhere, the behaviour suggests it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue, it's caused by the VM.

For **NGINX** in the location / block add the **sendfile off** setting.

```
location / {
    ...
    sendfile off;
}
```

For **Apache**, look for **EnableSendfile** in **httpd.conf** and set it to **off**:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

You must restart the services for the changes to take effect, hard refresh in your web browser (CTRL+F5) is required to see the change in effect.

> EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver files. This usually improves server performance, but **must be turned off when serving from networked-mounted filesystems** or support for these functions is otherwise broken on your system.

Comment: I finally got round to booting that problematic VM up.
Well frackin done mate! That's the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Errors same me ( \u0 ). I was fixed

1. sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf : change to sendfile off;
2. vagrant reload
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (clear cache of browser)
   => Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need go to in your VM and go in your server config. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and to put `sendfile` like off.

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    ...
    }
```

Comment: The OP does not seem to be using nginx and from your answer it is unclear why this would help. This doesn't seem to be an answer to the OPs actual question.