# Laravel returning a leading \u0 character on responses

Tags: laravel

In my localhost when i develop my web application and when i test web services with RestClient i get some `\u0` in response,

after copy files from localhost on server i dont get any this character and work fine

[image]

my code:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return response()->json(['a' => 'b']);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible you have a PHP file somewhere with characters *before* the opening `<?php `tag?

Comment: @TravisBritz i check it answer is no, code work fine on server, i'm not sure whats problem on my localhost

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47444825/6038111

Comment: @TravisBritz I'm not sure. i disabled `EnableSendfile` on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, i'm using ubuntu is it correct?